# evitar inyecciones y otros peligros en siguiente consulta sql

Tags: php, login, session, seguridad

buenas tardes, estoy haciendo un proyecto, lo quiero hacer lo más seguro posible.

Quisiera saber que debería modificar ahí para lograrlo.

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

```
include("conexion-bd.php");
session_start();

$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
echo $user;
echo $pass;
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as contar FROM edicion WHERE usuario = '$user' and password = '$pass'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

$cantidad = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

if($cantidad['contar'] >= 1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
    header("location: ../index.php");
}else{
   header("location: login.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
echo $user;
echo $pass;
```

Este código ya te expone a XSS.
Los parámetros debieran ser sanitizados y validados antes de ser usados y escapados antes de ser devueltos como html o para ser usados en html.

@BetaM ya te ha indicado un link sobre inyección de sql. Básicamente, no usar sql con los argumentos concatenados como strings, sino usar prepared statements.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as contar FROM edicion WHERE usuario = '$user' and password = '$pass'";
```

Hay bastante más a tener en cuenta, pero no está directamente relacionado con tu código.

**Nota al margen:** Estas mandando un `header` (`header("location:...)`), pero antes de eso hiciste un `echo`. No podés mandar `headers` luego de haber comenzado a enviar la respuesta (en el `body` del response), por que los headers vienen antes del body.

Comment: Discúlpame. El pero los "echo", los estaba usando para corroborar q llegaban bien los datos, un debug medio raro ja!